# How can I create two Onload functions at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i want to see if it is possible to create two onload functions at the same time.

e.g

```
<body onload="alert('test')">
<script>
alert("test")
</script>
```

This does not result 2 alert box's appearing at the same time. Is there a way to cause both to  function at the same time resulting multiple alert box's appearing on your screen?

Comment: `alert`s are blocking JS execution, so you can always only see one alert box at a time. But of course you can execute as many functions "onload" as you want.

Comment: alert is a blocking window. so you cannot have two alerts at the same time. the browser will show them one by one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2r7rU/ ? But don't expect two popups at same time, kinda side by side

Comment: You can't call onload twice on single time. However, you can alert twice or call multiple functions at a time. Like;

onload="alert('test'); alert('test2')";

Comment: It is possible to create multiple,by creating iframes above the body so it cause an eternal loop but that would be bad.

Comment: And why would you ever need this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a function and you can call other functions inside this.
for example;

```
function pageOnload()
{
   myAlert();
   sayHello("emre");
}

function myAlert()
{
  alert("my alert runs");
}

function sayHello(name)
{
   alert("hi " + name);
}
```

and after you can call "pageOnload()" method on your html

```
<body onload="pageOnload()">
```

Comment: Which would be exactly as effective as `<body onload="alert('my alert runs'); alert('hi emre')">`.  The functions don't make anything possible that wasn't already.

Comment: if you have two methods, it's ok, but if you have more or complex methods inside your logic, I prefer my way because of re-useability and readability, also maintance

Comment: Eh.  If we're gonna talk about reusability etc, it'd be better to attach event handlers via script.  But my point is, it doesn't do anything special -- in particular, it can't resolve the problem of the alert boxes not appearing simultaneously.